# Parsing a string using command Line parser

Tags: c#, arguments

I downloaded this package https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline
and I wanted to perform parsing for strings like

```
string str = "file:xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxxx.sh val:-a nsdd m";
```

so

```
file = xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxxx.sh
val = -a nsdd m
```

I wanted to know if anyone had a library in mind or has used the specified library to obtain the parameters specified in the string.
I am having a hard time understanding the example on how to parse that string and obtain the file parameter and val parameter. I know i could do string manipulation but I rather use an existing tested durable solution for this.

Comment: Why does `val` have all those things following it rather than splitting it on space and having `nsdd` and `m` as their own properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this library and it's a solid choice.

Here's a very basic sample using some of what you posted, see code comments for clarification.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // args a space separated array so you should use an array for your test
        // args are identified with the `-` so you should set args like `-f somefilenamehere`
        // args specified are -f and -v
        string[] arguments = new[] {"-f file:xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxxx.sh", "-v nsdd" };
        string file = string.Empty;
        string value = string.Empty;

        // you would pull your args off the options, if they are successfully parsed
        // and map them to your applications properties/settings
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(arguments)
            .WithParsed<Options>(o =>
            {
                file = o.InputFile; // map InputFile arg to file property
                value = o.Value; // map Value arg to value property
            });


        Console.WriteLine($"file = {file}");
        Console.WriteLine($"value = {value}");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // output:
        // file =  file:xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx.sh
        // value =  nsdd

    }        
}

// the options class is used to define your arg tokens and map them to the Options property
class Options
{
    [Option('f', "file", Required = true, HelpText = "Input files to be processed.")]
    public string InputFile { get; set; }

    [Option('v', "value", Required = true, HelpText = "Value to be used")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```